# Show incremented value of i in a console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to display an incremented value of an i in a loop of a console. That is, instead of showing "The object 0 has fallen", I want to display "The object 1 has fallen". How do I achieve this?

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
  {  
     Debug.Log("The object: " +(i+1)+ " has fallen");
  }
```

Comment: Exactly how you wrote it (or `Console.WriteLine` perhaps - I don't know enough about Unity to know whether `Debug` is sufficient). Are you saying it isn't working?

Comment: @mjwills the debug.log part is correct, in fact the whole question is already correctly answered in itself lol/

Comment: Debug.Log() should work without a problem, are you sure you are actually entering the if loop?

Comment: Ah the Debug.Log is working perfectly fine :P What I meant was how do I increment the value of i. When i=0, I want the console to display i=1 and so on.

Comment: That is **literally** what your code `(i + 1)` does.

Comment: @Andre could you add some sample output that you expect? Or write out your code without using a loop (so just a bunch of `Debug.Log` statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original sample works perfectly it already '

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {  
            Debug.Log("The object: " +(i+1)+ " has fallen");
        }
    }
}

public static class Debug
{
   public static void Log(string s) => Console.WriteLine(s);    
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q1shlY

prints:

```cs
The object: 1 has fallen
The object: 2 has fallen
The object: 3 has fallen
The object: 4 has fallen
The object: 5 has fallen
The object: 6 has fallen
```

You could of course also just start the loop at `1` instead of `0`, also notice the change for the condition in the for loop from `<` to `<=`:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++)
        {  
            Debug.Log("The object: " +i+ " has fallen");
        }
    }
}

public static class Debug
{
   public static void Log(string s) => Console.WriteLine(s);    
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rb76IS

prints:

```cs
The object: 1 has fallen
The object: 2 has fallen
The object: 3 has fallen
The object: 4 has fallen
The object: 5 has fallen
The object: 6 has fallen
```

A for-loop has 3 parts:
`for(<initial state, runs once at beginning>; <condition, runs while true>; <iterator, runs after each iteration>`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

So this does exactly what you're asking.